# Benchmarking ASP.net Web API Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a ASP.net Web API 2 project and would like to benchmark the time of each controller action.  My idea was to use ActionFilterAttribute and add a http header on the response containing the time taken.

Controller:

```
[Timing]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("get")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get() {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

ActionFilterAttribute:

```
public class TimingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer;
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null && actionExecutedContext.Response.Content !=null)
        {
                actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Execution-time", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get execution times of less than 1 second even though I have a 1s delay in the controller.  Does anyone know why this is the case or if there is a better way to benchmark Web API 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of things that are executed along the pipeline before OnActionExecuting is hit. Also, there are other things that are executed after OnActionExecuted, the most obvious being the HttpActionResult. Therefore It would be better to use [HttpApplication.BeginRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to start mesasuring time, and [HttpApplication.EndRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) to end measuring time.

However, I think there are better ways to benchmark a web application than log elapsed times at the server side. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) has lots of nice features related to benchmarking:

- You can capture the http traffic of interest by using filters.
- The statistics view, where you can see lots of statistics of the selected sessions.
- The time line view which shows you a nice chart about time taken by selected sessions.
- You can save the sessions into a sessions archive, this is a zip file containing all information about the sessions, including xml files with timing information, that you can analize later to build you own reports.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and found that [the solution on this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/db2972/trace-web-api-execution-time-using-custom-action-filter/) worked:

```
public class StopwatchAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
            actionContext.Request.Properties[actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName] = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
            Stopwatch stopwatch = (Stopwatch)actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties[actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName];

            if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null && actionExecutedContext.Response.Content != null)
            {
                actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Execution-Time", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```